# rotation of a real vauled function ( need help)

Tags: complex-analysis

If we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ ( say one is polynomial, one is exponential function) , $x$ could be complex not necessarily real.  For the equation $f(x)=g(x)$, I know that a possible method of finding real root is to use the graph of the two functions, but what about complex roots ? how can we determine the complex roots ?
In addition, if the equation becomes $f(x)=g(x)e^{i\theta}$ , how the roots changed from original equation ? Is there any relation between the two ?  I have this kind of thinking because the factor $e^{i\theta}$ is just like rotation of the $g(x)$ on the complex plan, am I right ?  Is anything in complex analysis related to this kind of question ?

Answer (score 0):

Graph  real and imaginary parts of f(x) and g(x) separately and solve two coupled equations.